# Show Only Icons using Conditional Formatting with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using the EPPlus package to make Excel documents with Conditional Formatting to apply an icon set to a range of cells.

```
using (ExcelRange scoreRange = workSheet.Cells[row, 28, row, 36])
 {
  ExcelAddress rangeAddress = new ExcelAddress(scoreRange.Address);
  var ruleIconSet = workSheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddThreeIconSet(rangeAddress, eExcelconditionalFormatting3IconsSetType.TrafficLights2);                                
 }
```

This works fine. However, I would like it to show ONLY the icon - and not the number at all. In Excel, this is a property of the ruleset - an option to 'Show Icon Only' - but I can't find this property in EPPlus

Answer (score 0):

This should work actually:

```
ruleIconSet.ShowValue = false;
```